# What's the name for face side view of face

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for English word which describes the photo of head facing sideways relative to camera.

For example in this mugshot:
[image: Mugshot, profile and full face]

The right photo is portrait, what would you call the left one? In my native language it's called "profile". But if I say profile photo, people will think Facebook profile photo.

Comment: You can refer to it as a _Side Profile_

Comment: RE: _But if I say profile photo, people will think Facebook profile photo_. That depends on the context. There are plenty of ways to disambiguate words with more than one meaning.

Comment: What an unfortunate choice of picture. That man was a *saint*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The photo on the left is a "profile", "profile view", or a photo taken "in profile".

And yes, online "profiles" do confuse the issue. OTOH, it's a nice look at language evolution if you think about how an online "profile" is a quick "outline" of the person.

The outline of a profile (the black-paper-on-white-background pieces you sometimes see) is called a silhouette.

Alternatively, in 3D modeling, this view might be called a left or right orthographic view, indicating it is one perspective on the 3D plane.

Comment: 'Profile view' also might be a common way of referring to this perspective of someone's 'head outline'...

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, they are both *portraits*:

> A painting, drawing, photograph, or engraving of a person, especially one depicting only the face or head and shoulders

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/portrait

The position of the head relative to the camera is irrelevant.

The one on the **left** is:

> a portrait in profile.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-profile?q=in+profile

The one on the **right** I would call:

> a front-on portrait

Comment: I don't think mug shots are portraits....

Answer (score 2):

It is called "profile" as well.  See, for example http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profile .  It comes from the practice of creating outlines by projecting the shadow of the figure and tracing the outline on the paper, and in majority of cases the figure was positioned so that the nose, lips, forehead were visible.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette or search for "silhouette art profile".

You can also call it "side shot" or "side view".

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "side shot" used. (British native-speaker.)

Comment: Well, at least now you've read one.  http://www.google.com/search?q=portrait+%22side+shot%22

Answer (score 0):

The first one is called "profile shot" or "side-view shot" It's usually taken to get a clear look of your jawline/nose/etc.

You can learn more about different types of shots on [Serif.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20170929044306/https://www.serif.com/appresources/MPX5/Tutorials/en-gb/tutorials/basics_shottypes.htm).